# Django rest framework. custom urls

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need some api urls:

```
/api/<id>/<filter>/
/api/<id>,<id>,<id>/<filter>/
```

Where id is model id and filter custom parameter. How can I make the urls with rest framework?

I have model Image and want request server for json with custom fields list from model and calculated with 'filter' parameter value.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just use a query string? `/api/filter/?id=27`

Comment: Hm, what about id list params and filter arg?

Comment: Thanks for response, rest framework makes work such that you say.

Answer (score 1):

Official doc might help you regarding filtering 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/